# Projected coordinates for Well-known ID 5232 cannot be found in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3

Projected coordinates for SLD99(WKID- 5232) cannot be found in ArcMap Coordinate system.
 Is there any built in procedure to find that original coordinate system in ArcMap 10.3? If not what is the procedure to define that coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5232 is for a coordinate operation, not a projected coordinate reference system. Try looking for 5235, SLD99 Sri Lanka Grid 1999 or possibly 5234, Kandawala Sri Lanka Grid. Both were added in ArcGIS 10.1.0.

If you're using the coordinate system "browser," they're in projected coordinate systems, National Grids, Asia.

A coordinate operation includes:

```
name
method
parameter values needed for the method
```

One example is a coordinate operation used for a UTM zone. The definition for zone 11 North is:

```
EPSG:16011
UTM Zone 11 North
Transverse Mercator
central meridian: -117.0
latitude of origin: 0.0
scale factor: 0.9996
false easting: 500000.0
false northing: 0.0
```

Now this definition can be used with different geographic coordinate reference system to create different projected coordinate reference systems. This leads to 32611, WGS 84 / UTM Zone 11 North, 26911, NAD83 / UTM Zone 11 North, and 26711, NAD27 / UTM Zone 11 North.

In your case, the coordinate operation (conversion) 5232, Sri Lanka Grid 1999, is used to build the projected coordinate reference system, 5235, SLD99 / Sri Lanka Grid 1999.

Disclosure: I work at Esri and I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry.

Comment: What is the difference between coordinate operation and projected coordinate reference system? SLD99 and kandawala grid have different coordinates for same reference point. (SLD99 500000,500000 while kandawala 200000,200000) I have been taught once to define that initially. Once you setup that for first time we were able use it continuously.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include information about coordinate operation.